# Выпадающее меню не отрабатывает cookie

Tags: javascript, cookie, menu

Моя задача состоит в том, чтобы меню запоминало текущее состояние, когда открыт целый "аккордеон" и при переходе по ссылке на определенный сегмент товара, запоминало состояние "аккордеона".
 HTML не полный, так как сейчас стоит цель прийти к реализации запоминания при открытии хотя бы `1-lvl` меню.
Индекс куки принимает и вроде бы как отдаёт, но запоминание состояния не происходит.
 Где я туплю ?

Js code :

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

  var checkCookie = $.cookie('nav-item');
  if (checkCookie != null) {
    $('#nav > ul:eq('+checkCookie+')').show();
  }

  $('#nav > li > a').click(function(){
      var navIndex = $('#nav > li > a').index(this);
      $.cookie('nav-item', 'navIndex'); 
    }); 

  $('#nav > li > span').click(function(){
      var navIndex = $('#nav > li > span').index(this);
      $.cookie('nav-item', navIndex);
    });

    $('#nav > li > span').click(function() {
        $("#nav ul").toggleClass('active');
    });
});
```

HTML code:

```
<div class="menu-categories-container">
        <ul id="nav">
            <li class="menu-item-has-children-1"><span class="open-lvl-1"></span><a href="#">Изделия из дерева
                </a>

            <ul class="menu-lvl-1">
                <li><a href="">Декор</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Геральдика</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Двери</a></li>
                <li><span class="open-lvl-1"></span><a href="">Декоративное панно</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Рамы и зеркала</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item-has-children-lvl-2">
                    <span class="open-lvl-1"></span>
                    <a href="">Резные лестницы из<br> дерева</a>
                    <ul class="menu-lvl-2">
                            <li><a href="">Балясины резные</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Заходные столбы</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><span class="open-lvl-1"></span><a href="">Религия</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Токарная обработка</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Часы</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
            <li class="menu-item-has-children-2"><span class="open-lvl-1"></span><a href="#">Художественное литьё</a>

        </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Куки - плохое место для хранения данных. Используйте localStorage для тех данных, которые не нужны вам на сервере при каждом запросе.

Comment: `$.cookie('nav-item', 'navIndex');`  вы сохраняете строку, а не значение переменной

Comment: Это был тест для отрабоки. <span> без кавычек не просто так.

Comment: Да какие данные, мне нужно всего лишь меню которое будет запоминать своё состояние( ветку открытий) т.е. не будет захлопываться при переходе по ссылке.

Comment: Такие данные, зачем вам это состояние на сервере в каждом запросе? Куки всегда отсылаются в заголовках запроса, генерируя лишний трафик. От плохих привычек лучше избавляться заранее.

Comment: Кстати, вы уверены, что `$('#nav > ul:eq('+checkCookie+')').show();` делает то, что нужно? У вас в `#nav` много списков, и некоторые скрыты? Или кому-то нужно добавить класс active? Если подразумевается индекс среди всех списков, включая вложенные - вероятно придётся сохранять весь путь от корня до нужного.

Comment: Ну, я читал, что метод .show() -  добавляет выбранному классу display: block; Вот я и решил его использовать. В реальной модели - да, списков и под-списков много.  Вероятно да. Только нужно ли для этого каждый под-список ul - делать уникальным и для него прописывать код.

Comment: Нужно понимать, что это не отобразит список, если его родитель скрыт

Comment: А родитель и не должен будет скрываться.

Comment: Проблема в том что я с вёрсткой списка столкнулся впервые. И с задачей реализации "умного" меню тоже. Так уж вышло. Я не жалуюсь, просто по ходу решения задачи, всплывают ошибки и  постоянно приходится вносить правки.

Comment: Главный навык программиста - умение разбивать задачу на более мелкие подзадачи. Отдельная задача само меню, отдельная - сохранить/восстановить некие данные, отдельная - использовать этот механизм для состояния меню..

Comment: Спасибо. Еще вопрос - почему вы использовали localStorage.menuIndex  а не localStorage.setItem? Я не нашёл информации про метод .menuIndex();

Comment: Стоп. menuIndex - просто ключ, под которым я храню число) По нему же и достаю. С тем же успехом это могло быть `localStorage.mySavedMenuIndexFromPreviousVisit` или `localStorage[key]`

Answer (score 1):

Используйте localStorage:

Сохранить значение:

```
localStorage.menuIndex = $(this).closest('li').index();
```

Загрузить значение:

```
let index = localStorage.menuIndex || 0;
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n951Lysv/)

---

А ваша ошибка в том, что вы пытаетесь получить индекс элемента(`a`, `span`), который лежит в контейнере в одиночестве.

Нужно запрашивать `index()` именно у `li`:

```
$(this).closest('li').index();
// или
$('#nav > li > span').parent().index();
```

Comment: span это пространство для + который является псевдоелементами этого span и рисует + и ставит на его место нарисованный - при открытии меню

Comment: К чему это? Вам же нужен индекс li'шки? Ну так доберитесь до неё сначала. closest() - самый простой путь

Comment: У меня меню выпадающее, значит сбоку справа у меня span - в нем 2 псеводелемента + и - . При клике  + становиться - . Так вот мне нужно что бы насколько бы уровней меню не открывалось и по каким ссылкам не переходили - оно оставалось открыто таким каким было, а не схлопывалось. По сути клики происходят по <a> и по <span>

Comment: Вам меню сделать, я не пойму? Это на ТЗ больше похоже. В вопросе точно это всё есть?

Comment: Да это моё ТЗ. Я уже 2 недели бьюсь над его реализацией. Впроде бы как все работает, но с моим кодом при перезагрузке страницы, состояние меню не сохраняется

Comment: Сейчас я почитаю о localStorage разберусь как работает и буду пробовать внедрять его раз вы говорите что это лучше чем cookie. Извиняюсь но я начинающий разработчик, могу тупить, не знать, не понимать, но я стараюсь. Наверное следовало до конца изучить курс и учебник JS прежде чем в jQuery лезть )

Comment: Просто мы тут как бы на вопросы отвечаем, а не чужую работу делаем. Если вы сможете оформить вашу проблему в виде понятного вопроса, вероятно с этой проблемой вам тут помогут.

Comment: Я и не хочу что бы мою работу сделали. Мне интересно самому решить задачу, просто я зашел в тупик и решил поискать ответы на вопросы - где и в чем я застрял. Спасибо, в след раз буду более подробно и внимательно описывать свою проблему.